# How to create an EXE file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How can I create an EXE file for a VB.NET project. I tried with file -> New project -> setup and deployment -> setup wizard.

But I can't include SQL Server 2000 database. Showing error

> Error. Unable to find source file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\eg_Log.LDF' for file 'eg_Log.LDF', located in '[TARGETDIR]', the file may be absent or locked.    C:\Documents and Settings\XP\Desktop\egg\Setup1\Setup1.vdproj   Setup1

Comment: the question isn't very clear

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server puts a hard lock on the database files when it is running.  Stop it first with the service manager.